# PostgreSQL - how to pass role name as a parameter to the procedure?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a procedure to automate some role management tasks. I am following PgSql documentation for version 12 and trying to create following procedure:

```
# create or replace procedure xk_create_role(role regrole)

language plpgsql

as $$

begin

execute format('create role %L', role);

end;

$$;
```

no matter what formatting I am using, or without formatting it does not creates role with a given name, but with "role"....

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks,
S.

Comment: You need to declare the parameter as `text`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks man, worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `regrole` type expects what you pass to be a valid role in your database, so take the `role` parameter as `text`.

The `%L` formats what you pass as a literal, so it will be enclosed in quotes before execution.  You want `%I`, which formats it as an identifier.

Try this:

```
create or replace procedure xk_create_role(role text)
language plpgsql
as $$
  begin
    execute format('create role %I', role);
  end;
$$;

call xk_create_role('testingrole');
```